# Sed: Use matched text in substitution

Tags: regex, sed

How can I use `sed` so that when it finds a match, I can use it in the substitution field?

For example

```
echo "12a34" | sed 's/a/#bcd/g'
12abcd34
```

What do I replace the `#` with to get the expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `&`:

```
echo '12a34' | sed 's/a/&bcd/g'
12abcd34
```

`&` in the replacement clause of a  `s///` command refers to what the pattern matched, which is the `a` in this case.

This particular case doesn't show very well how it works, since `a` is not a very interesting regular expression, so let me add a better example:

```
echo foobar | sed 's/[fb]/&42/g'
f42oob42ar
```

where the `f` and the `b` are matched by `[fb]` and subsequently replaced with `f42` and `b42`.